# Using POST with PHP, how can I send multiple files at once?

Tags: php, xml, curl, post

I am trying to upload 1000 products to a website. The website allows for only 100 products at a time. Right now I have split my 1000 products into 10 files (each with 100 products). I have a PHP file that loads one of the files and posts it to the website with curl. `$xml=simplexml_load_file("file_name_1.xml")`

```
// send data with curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://website_name/api/save');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('data'=>($data))));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

// decode response
$all=json_decode($result);
```

This works for sending only one file, as it only sends *file_name_1.xml*. I have 10 other php files that do the same but with the other xml files.

I would like to be able to do this with only 2 files, 1 php file and 1 big xml or with 11 files - 1 php and 10 xmls. Both work.

I would guess to be able to use only 1 php files I would need to wait for the API to respond back and then I could send another file? If that is the case and this is at all possible my question is, how do I send multiple xml files with PHP curl while making sure the PHP stacks them and sends them one after another?

Let me know if I need to give more code example. Thank you!

Comment: Make then Mime Attachments.  Each attachment starts with a new line with two dashes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140), and https://www.onlinecode.org/sending-mime-type-files-using-curl-php/

Comment: If you are talking about restrictions in "simultaneous" file upload. Please check the php.ini file's `max_file_uploads` value